# Executing all the scripts within a directory using a bash script

Tags: r, bash, shell, execution, slurm

I'd like to run all the r scripts located in a directory called `scripts` using a bash script. How would you do it? My script so far (not working) looks as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
 
#SBATCH --job-name=name
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
 
module load R/4.0.2-gnu9.1
module load sqlite/3.26.0
 
Rscript $R_SCRIPT
```

Comment: `for script in scripts/*.r; do Rscript "$script"; done`

Comment: You mean I should put your line instead of `Rscript $R_SCRIPT`?

Comment: I think so. That will loop over the directory and execute each of the scripts. Your code never sets `$R_SCRIPT`.

Comment: Are you wanting to execute them all in serial on the same slurm allocated node, or are you expecting to execute them in parallel over a SLURM managed cluster on independent nodes ?

Comment: Very good question, I wanted to execute them on several nodes if possible